# Redirecting stdout and stderr logs with Apache Mesos slave

Tags: mesos

The default location of stdout and stderr logs are stored in `/tmp` in Apache Mesos.

I would like to store them in `/home/anil/std/stdout`

Please let me know how I can do this without affecting the standard Mesos logs

Answer (score 2):

Are we talking about the mesos master/slave stdout or about the sandbox (i.e. task) stdout?

**Sandbox/Task output**

Have a look at the workDir [config](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/configuration/) parameter: *--work_dir=VALUE Directory path to place framework work directories (default: /tmp/mesos)*

**Normal master/slave logging**

- There is the logDir flag *--log_dir=VALUE    Location to put log files (no default, nothing is written to disk unless specified; does not affect logging to stderr)*
- If you are using the mesosphere packages and run mesos as a service:  There are wrapper scripts actually taking care of starting mesos.

I hope I understood your problem correctly.
Joerg

Comment: i am interested in Sandbox and i have mentioned the --workdir and i am seeing the mesos logs in the directory mentioned but haven't specified the --log_dir ... I would like to know if i give the path for log_dir will my sandbox logs move to the mentioned path . and will it anyway effect eh existing mesos logs

Comment: to be specific i want to move the STDerr and STDOut files to a specific directory . I tried it specifying the log_dir but the stderr and stdout files still go to /tmp folder . I can create a sym link to the /tmp file but i want to rename the files as well . in that case i need to the slave-id and framework-id . Is there a way i can figure theslaveid and framework-id programmatically ont he box

Answer (score 1):

If you want access the logs outside the slave(s) you can try out https://github.com/cloudflare/complainer.

> Complainer's job is to send notifications to different services when tasks fail on Mesos cluster. While your system should be reliable to failures of individual tasks, it's nice to know when things fail and why.
>
> **Supported log upload services:**
>
> - No-op - keeps URLs to Mesos slave sandbox.
> - S3 - both AWS S3 and on-premise S3-compatible API.
>
> **Supported reporting services:**
>
> - Sentry - a great crash reporting software.
> - Hipchat - not so great communication platform.
> - Slack - another communication platform.
> - File - regular file stream output, including stdout/stderr.

The tool is under heavy development right now and is used for example in trivago's log mesos stack.